# Create a build file git push gitlab ci

Tags: git, gitlab, psql, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working on a plsql project (with a lot of stored procedure(SP)) hosted on my gitlab server, every SP is on a single file. I want create a new file on every build (using gitlab-ci) that contains the changes of the SP.
My question is how can I get the list of the files with his status (new, delete or modified) between every build? Remember that I am running gitlab-ci with gitlab-runner, and the runner fetch the changes before that I have the chances of made a git diff.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Log from the build gitlab-ci

```
Using Shell executor...
Running on rsdesa11...
Fetching changes...
Removing Common/target/
Removing core/target/
Removing loader/target/
Removing model/target/
HEAD is now at 86266c3
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you already have a runner / shared runner. If not check out:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/linux-repository.md

It depends a bit on your gitlab-ci-runner. If you have a shell runner (when you register your runner, select "shell"), you can specify a gitlab-ci.yml with arbitary bash commands you want to execute.

```
job_title:
  script:
    ls -la
    git diff 12345 > my_diff.txt
```

The rest is bash magic that highly depends on how your setup looks like, how your folders look like and so on.

Docker runners are a bit more complicated and in general require a bit more knowledege about docker commands and volumes to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I already have a runner.
I don't want the difference, I need the files that has been modified with his status (new, delete, changed) because I have to execute the entire SP into the database. And the things is that the runner execute the pull before I have the chance of made a git diff...